# How do I display a different JLabel depending on a condition in my Applet

Tags: java

I am trying to display a new JLabel depending on a condition and delete the current one that is there already.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Applet extends JApplet {

    JTextField value1, value2, value3;

    private String text;
    public JLabel jLabel;


    public void init () {

        JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Please enter 3 RGB values between 0 and 255");
        JButton but = new JButton("Create");

        but.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));

        value1 = new JTextField(5);
        value2 = new JTextField(5);
        value3 = new JTextField(5);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(prompt);
        add(value1);
        add(value2);
        add(value3);
        add(but);

        TextPanel panel = new TextPanel(this);

        text = "Welcome to my Applet";


        Color col = new Color(255,255,255);

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(text);
        jLabel.setForeground(Color.green);

        panel.add(jLabel);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    class TextPanel extends JPanel {
        Applet x;
        TextPanel (Applet app) {
            x = app;
        }

    }

    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        private Applet theApplet;
        public ButtonHandler(Applet app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            String text = theApplet.value1.getText();
            String text1 = theApplet.value2.getText();
            String text2 = theApplet.value3.getText();

            theApplet.value1.setText("");
            theApplet.value2.setText("");
            theApplet.value3.setText("");
```

Here is the condition that I am trying to use. I am trying to make it such that if the user does not enter all three RGB values a message will be placed in the centre. I have tried to use .length() but and tried to set the text to the appropriate message but the message in the centre is not changing.

```
if (text.length() == 0 || text1.length() == 0 || text2.length() == 0) {
    jLabel.setText("Can you please enter 3 RGB values");
}
```

Comment: are you trying to change the background color of the JLabel or remove the old JLabel?

Comment: I am trying to replace the old JLabel with the new one if the condition is met

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a swing component, you need to do:

```
container.remove(oldLabel);
container.add(newLabel);
container.revalidate();
```

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    final JLabel oldLabel = new JLabel("Old");
    final JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("New");

    JButton jButton = new JButton("Replace Label");
    final JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.add(oldLabel);
    jFrame.add(jPanel);
    jFrame.add(jButton);
    jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (1 < 2) { // replace with you own condition
                jPanel.remove(oldLabel);
                jPanel.add(newLabel);
                jPanel.revalidate();
            }
        }
    });

    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.pack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `init` method you have this line:

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(text);
```

This means that you are defining a new, local variable, which is assigned the new `JLabel` object. This object is the one you are adding to your panel.

However, the `jLabel` that is defined as a field in the `Applet` class is not assigned this value. It remains with its initial value (null, I assume). The local variable obscures it.

In the event handler, the local variable from `init` is no longer visible. So you don't have any access to the actual label you have created. It tries to change the `jLabel` *field*, but that is not the JLabel in the panel.

The solution is simple: instead of

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(text);
```

You have to use

```
jLabel = new JLabel(text);
```

That is - don't declare a local variable, but assign to the existing field. Once you do that, you'll be able to change that `jLabel` from within the event handler. Don't forget to repaint.